# Is there a reason I've been unable to get Tally Counters from drops on Terraria (iOS)?

Tags: terraria-mobile

I've been recently trying to make a cell phone before I enter hardmode for which I need Tally counter. Tally counter  drops from rusty bones in dungeon. With water candles and battle potion I farmed for it for 10 min real time but no luck. I've got a dozen of bone wands, several nazars and 5 clother voodo dolls which has even smaller chance.

Same with compass from mother slime and metal detector from nymph.
Am I having a really really bad luck, or these items don't drop in mobile version?

All wikis that I've found don't mark these items as console or PC content only. 
If mobile version doesn't have these drops, then what are other items one shouldn't expect to loot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [the wiki](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Tally_Counter) mentions, the Tally Counter only exists in the PC version of Terraria.

Comment: Yeah, some why 2 wiki apps I was using didn't mark it.

Comment: @MrCheatak no need for that. Others may have use for this as well. Remember, this isn't just a site for you to get answers.